# Is "Real world usages" question offtopic?

Tags: discussion

Currently there is the question on the mainsite called [Real world usages of statistical analyses](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330/real-world-usages-of-statistical-analysis)

What is your opinion. Should we allow this kind of questions or not.

The question is:

> Where do you use statistical analysis
>   at work? Do you use it in a company?
>   What problems is it solving?

Answer (score 8):

I think the question could be reworded to make it a bit more interesting.  For example,

> I keep saying the sexy job in the next
>   ten years will be statisticians.
>   People think I’m joking, but who
>   would’ve guessed that computer
>   engineers would’ve been the sexy job
>   of the 1990s?”
>
> Hal Varian, The
>   McKinsey Quarterly, January 2009.

What jobs, do think, are being referred to?

Oh, and make it a community wiki.

Comment: Better, better. This doesn't invite for other "Real world usage of X"-questions. However, it is still quite subjective.

Comment: Subjectivity in and of itself isn't a problem so long as they're market CW.  Some of these questions can be very rewarding.  Although there's no doubt that this is a very poorly considered question.

Answer (score 3):

I am only curious whether there are any non-real world uses ;-)

Comment: By non-real world I mean academic research.

Comment: Than I feel offended; except for some heavy theoreticians we all work hard to be applied.

Comment: That is a misunderstanding. I consider academic research to be harder than engineering. Only the first inventor is recognized.
I can read the research papers. But I don't know how statistics is used in companies.

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't a great question, I think that it should be fine as a community wiki.  There might be some interesting "use cases" that come out of it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this question does not belong on this website.

Firstly, this is a site for experts. The intended users of this sites are using their stuff in the real world (yes, universities are also real world in this topic)

As we are all experts, this question has no purpose on this site. It only invites to summing up broad topics, or not being specific on the application anyway. A list of possible applications of statistical analyses is something you expect on a wikipedia-page (which is targeted on novices), not on an expert site.

Especially in the beginning of this site, I would suggest to not have this topics. If this is allowed now, every question of "Real world usages of method X" where X is an related method would possible qualify for the site.

IMHO this site should be a Q&A site, not a site for getting inspiration, hearing great stories, or bragging about your job.

Comment: While I wish you were right, if this site was just for experts and we were all experts, then there wouldn't be questions like this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-standard-deviation.

Comment: @Shane That's a good point. As I'm not graduated yet I should maybe not call myself an expert either. However I think this site is to help people answering their questions, not having a subjective discussion, only useful for non-expert readers.